# What is the difference between string constant and string between quotes " " ? and how to convert between them?

Tags: javascript, node.js, string

I call an async funtcion

```
const root = 'something'
await FetchMamRestricted.execute(root)
```

no output will appear.But if I write

```
await FetchMamRestricted.execute('something')
```

It work!!
Could anyone tell me how I could make it work using 'root' variable?
Thanks in advance.

Edit:
I know JavaScript language doesn't behave this way. What I think about the problem is
 the `FetchMamRestricted.execute('something')` content is:

```
const execute = async (_root) => {
  // Callback used to pass data + returns next_root
  console.log("inside function root is",_root) // outptut 'something'
  const resp = await Mam.fetch(_root, mamType, mamSecret, logData)
}
```

I think the function `Mam.fetch(_root, mamType, mamSecret, logData)` have a bug(it's a build in function) on checking the first parameter using something like '==' not '==='.So it won't work unless I parse the string between '' to the parameter.

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? What you describe is *not* how JavaScript behaves.

Comment: okay, I will edit the question now.

Comment: @VLAZ I tried to give more details.It will be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. It was just a bug with the function initializing the `const root`. It was adding some white spaces to the string to reach a certain length. This is why the two strings were different.